# Visual Studio C++ : Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, runtime-error, assertion

I recently tried to create a program that can read an ODBC database then write the entries in an Excel file by using the CRecordset class, the program complilates perfectly, but the problems come in the execution...

First error :

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\Windows\system32\mfc140ud.dll
>
> File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin1.inl
>
> Line: 24

Second error :

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\Windows\system32\mfc140ud.dll
>
> File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp
>
> Line: 3312

The two errors are pointing toward the mfc140ud.dll file, it's not a missing file, so it's not the problem.

Here is the function where the exception is raised:

```
void parseDB(CRecordset &rs, const CString &SqlString, CString strOut) {

std::cout << "test2";

rs.Open(CRecordset::snapshot, SqlString, CRecordset::readOnly);
std::string entry;
std::fstream file;

std::cout << "test3";

while(!rs.IsEOF()) {

    std::cout << "test4";
    rs.GetFieldValue((short)0, strOut);
    CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString = strOut; 
    entry = pszConvertedAnsiString;

    writeXLSX(entry.c_str(), file);

    rs.MoveNext();

}

rs.Close();

}
```

The "std::cout << "test"" are here for debugging, and my program generates these errors right after the "test2" display, so I deducted that the error comes from the "Open" line.

This is the way I initialize the CRecordset:

```
CString sDsn;
CDatabase db;
CRecordset rs(&db);
CString strOut;
CString SqlString;
```

Then, I use a CALL SQL function in a switch-case:

```
switch (sequence) {
        case 1:
            SqlString = "CALL GETCUSNAME(AGENTS)";
            break;
        case 2:
            SqlString = "CALL GETCUSNAME(CLIENT)";
            break;
        default:
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Wrong entry!"));
        }
```

I searched on many sites and I couldn't find an answer, that's why I ask a question here, thanks by advance.

Comment: What are the errors? Show their text in the question, not as links to pictures on other web sites.

Comment: Please do not just put the errors in your question as a link to an image, but instead type out the (relevant parts of the) error message as text in your question. If future people google the relevant error, they will see this question. Your question also does not seem to be a valid [MCVE] as it contains unclosed opening braces.

Comment: The second assertion indicates something wrong with the state of your record set or SQL string. What's the SQL you're passing?

Comment: Also, how are you initializing the CRecordSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first assertion comes from `AfxGetResourceHandle` complaining that it has not been set up correctly.

This will usually happen because you either didn't call `AfxWinInit` at the start of your application (if you have a console application and didn't set it up with the MFC wizard, this is very likely the case), or you're writing an MFC DLL called from non-MFC code, and you didn't add `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ));` at the start of every externally visible function.

I believe the second is because MFC requires you to wrap CALL queries in curly braces, like so: `{CALL GETCUSNAME(AGENTS)}`. Otherwise the call is not recognized, and code execution enters a path it is not supposed to take.

Comment: Thanks ! One assertion fixed !

Now the other is remaining, and for me, it's the worst one.

Comment: I think I found the cause for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, I found out this happens only in debug builds, cuz I was building an addin for certain desktop software and I was calling my MFC Dialogue inside this software. However, the problem was that this software was using release MFC Library (MFC140u.dll) while my dialogue debug build was using (MFC140ud.dll), I tried putting the (MFC140ud.dll) file in my project file and point vs and the software to load it. nut didn't work. The solution that worked for me was addin a Conditional Compilation preprocessor snippet to undefine DEBUG before including MFC headers. Then redefine DEBUG if it was defined before. in my pre-compiled header file.

```
#pragma once

#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#undef _DEBUG
#define NDEBUG
#endif

// -- Windows and MFC Inclusions --

#include "afxwin.h"
#include "afx.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include <Windows.h>

// -- Project Inclusions --
#include <xxxxx.h>

#if defined(_AFXEXT) && defined(__cplusplus)
#include <afxcoll.h>
#endif
#endif //PCH_H
```